# SQL - Does row match max of sums

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am getting a little tripped up with a SQL query. Here is some background.

Schema:

```
Product(pid, price, color),
Order(cid, pid, quantity),
Customer(cid, name, age)
```

I want to get the pid of the most ordered product (greatest quantity).

I have managed to determine the max value with:

```
Select Max(total) 
From (Select Sum(quantity) as total 
      From Orders Group By pid) as Totals
```

but I am getting stuck trying to match which products are in this subquery. Here is what I have tried:

```
Select pid, SUM(quantity) as q 
From Orders 
Where q in (
    Select Max(total) 
    From (Select Sum(quantity) as total 
          From Orders 
          Group By pid) as Totals
    ) 
Group By pid
```

This says that q is an unknown column.

Any suggestions on how I could do this or do it better?

Answer (score 1):

you can do a `JOIN` along with `GROUP BY` like

```
select p.*
from product p
join
(select pid from Order
 group by pid having quantity = max(quantity)
) tab on p.pid = tab.pid;
```

In your posted query it's erroring `q is an unknown column` cause `q` is a column alias which you are trying to use in `WHERE` condition; which is not allowed.

Comment: Thanks! But it says quantity is unknown in the having clause

Comment: @JonathanBrown, try changing the inner select list to `select pid, quantity from orders`

Comment: that fixed the error (I shoulda caught that), but unfortunately the query doesn't return the correct results. [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c2abc/51)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to simply include the `PID` in the original query because you are grouping on it. Then `ORDER BY` and and get only the top result using `LIMIT 1`.

```
SELECT
    pid
   ,Sum(quantity) as total 
FROM
    Orders 
GROUP BY 
    pid
ORDER BY      
    Sum(quantity)
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Thanks. I am trying to avoid using LIMIT 1 because I want to return any results that may be tied for the most

Comment: Fair, in that case both Gordon's and sgeddes' answer are more useful. Stylistically I think I would prefer using MAX to LIMIT, but look at the performance/query plan to see how they run.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way you can do it using a subquery with `limit`:

```
select o.pid, sum(o.quantity)
from `order` o
group by o.pid
having sum(o.quantity) = 
(
    select sum(quantity) 
    from `order`
    group by pid
    order by sum(quantity) desc
    limit 1
)
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/28d942/5)

Answer (score 1):

If you want only one most ordered product, then Karl's answer is fine.  If you want all that have the same quantity, then:

```
select pid, sum(quantity) as quantity
from orders o
group by pid
having sum(quantity) = (select max(quantity)
                        from (select sum(quantity) as quantity
                              from orders o
                              group by pid
                             ) q
                       );
```